# Is 2-sigma limit applicable as a measure of variance to a distribution?

Tags: normal-distribution, variance, standard-deviation

There is a paper that uses something like the 2-sigma limit to check if a quantity is more-or-less constant. More specifically in [this paper](http://research.microsoft.com/pubs/149305/1509.pdf) on Text Detection (Sec. 3.2 3rd para last line) this limit is used to check for constant stroke width i.e. something like if mean > 2*sigma. This relation is not explicitly stated in the paper (it writes about a paragraph to the same effect), so I tested it on text and works reasonably well in discriminating between text/non-text on the basis of constant stroke-width.

The question is - why is the 2*sigma limit applicable as a measure of a quantity's constant nature? And in case this limit is satisfied, what conclusions can be drawn? Also interested in mathematically proving what is obtained from experimental results. Basically I am searching for a proper background on the 2-sigma limit: [this one](http://www.physicsforums.com/showthread.php?t=145743) isn't so helpful.

Comment: The paper does not appear to create a two-sigma limit: it refers to an *empirical* determination of a variance threshold used in a highly specialized application.  The present question seems to generalize from this to "a quantity's constant nature," but I see no intention in the paper to do so, nor can I imagine any statistical justification for such an unfounded statement.  Are you perhaps quoting something else?

Comment: yes, the paper states that they experimentally determined it. However it is basically the 2-sigma limit. So if experimental results tally closely with the limit (I tried it independently on same dataset) then can we say that the 2-sigma limit is applicable as the results tally?

Comment: I'm not sure what to make of such a statement, because it sounds tautological: "we found that two SDs works, so...two SDs is applicable."  I guess it all comes down to what you mean by "applicable."  The authors are probably hoping that this is applicable to recognizing text within many images.  I doubt they hope it is applicable to any other problem.

Comment: hmm. that does blow the wind out of my sails somewhat. hopefully there can be some background theory on the 2-sigma.